# kafka mongodb sink connector issue while writing to mongodb

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-kafka-connector

I am facing issue while writing to mongodb using mongo kafka sink connector.I am using mongodb of v5.0.3 and Strimzi kafka of v2.8.0. I have added p1/mongo-kafka-connect-1.7.0-all.jar and p2/mongodb-driver-core-4.5.0.jar in connect cluster plugins path.Created connector using below

```
{
  "name": "mongo-sink",
  "config": {
     "topics": "sinktest2",
     "connector.class": "com.mongodb.kafka.connect.MongoSinkConnector",
     "tasks.max": "1",
     "connection.uri": "mongodb://mm-0.mongoservice.st.svc.cluster.local:27017,mm-1.mongoservice.st.svc.cluster.local:27017",
     "database": "sinkdb",
     "collection": "sinkcoll",
     "mongo.errors.tolerance": "all",
     "mongo.errors.log.enable": true,
     "errors.log.include.messages": true,
     "errors.deadletterqueue.topic.name": "sinktest2.deadletter",
     "errors.deadletterqueue.context.headers.enable": true
     }
}

root@ubuntuserver-0:/persistent# curl  http://localhost:8083/connectors/mongo-sink/status
{"name":"mongo-sink","connector":{"state":"RUNNING","worker_id":"localhost:8083"},"tasks":[{"id":0,"state":"RUNNING","worker_id":"localhost:8083"}],"type":"sink"}
```

When I check the status after creating connector it is showing running, but when I start sending records to kafka topic connector is running into issues.connector status is showing as below.

```
root@ubuntuserver-0:/persistent# curl  http://localhost:8083/connectors/mongo-sink/status
{
   "name":"mongo-sink",
   "connector":{
      "state":"RUNNING",
      "worker_id":"localhost:8083"
   },
   "tasks":[
      {
         "id":0,
         "state":"FAILED",
         "worker_id":"localhost:8083",
         "trace":"org.apache.kafka.connect.errors.ConnectException: Tolerance exceeded in error handler\n\tat org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.errors.RetryWithToleranceOperator.execAndHandleError(RetryWithToleranceOperator.java:206)\n\tat org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.errors.RetryWithToleranceOperator.execute(RetryWithToleranceOperator.java:132)\n\tat org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.convertAndTransformRecord(WorkerSinkTask.java:496)\n\tat org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.convertMessages(WorkerSinkTask.java:473)\n\tat org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.poll(WorkerSinkTask.java:328)\n\tat org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.iteration(WorkerSinkTask.java:232)\n\tat org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.execute(WorkerSinkTask.java:201)\n\tat org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask.doRun(WorkerTask.java:182)\n\tat org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask.run(WorkerTask.java:231)\n\tat java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)\n\tat java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)\n\tat java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)\n\tat java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)\n\tat java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)\nCaused by: org.apache.kafka.connect.errors.DataException: Converting byte[] to Kafka Connect data failed due to serialization error: \n\tat org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter.toConnectData(JsonConverter.java:324)\n\tat org.apache.kafka.connect.storage.Converter.toConnectData(Converter.java:87)\n\tat org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.convertValue(WorkerSinkTask.java:540)\n\tat org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.lambda$convertAndTransformRecord$2(WorkerSinkTask.java:496)\n\tat org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.errors.RetryWithToleranceOperator.execAndRetry(RetryWithToleranceOperator.java:156)\n\tat org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.errors.RetryWithToleranceOperator.execAndHandleError(RetryWithToleranceOperator.java:190)\n\t... 13 more\nCaused by: org.apache.kafka.common.errors.SerializationException: com.fasterxml.jackson.core.io.JsonEOFException: Unexpected end-of-input: expected close marker for Object (start marker at [Source: (byte[])\"{  \"; line: 1, column: 1])\n at [Source: (byte[])\"{  \"; line: 1, column: 4]\nCaused by: com.fasterxml.jackson.core.io.JsonEOFException: Unexpected end-of-input: expected close marker for Object (start marker at [Source: (byte[])\"{  \"; line: 1, column: 1])\n at [Source: (byte[])\"{  \"; line: 1, column: 4]\n\tat com.fasterxml.jackson.core.base.ParserMinimalBase._reportInvalidEOF(ParserMinimalBase.java:664)\n\tat com.fasterxml.jackson.core.base.ParserBase._handleEOF(ParserBase.java:486)\n\tat com.fasterxml.jackson.core.base.ParserBase._eofAsNextChar(ParserBase.java:498)\n\tat com.fasterxml.jackson.core.json.UTF8StreamJsonParser._skipWSOrEnd2(UTF8StreamJsonParser.java:3033)\n\tat com.fasterxml.jackson.core.json.UTF8StreamJsonParser._skipWSOrEnd(UTF8StreamJsonParser.java:3003)\n\tat com.fasterxml.jackson.core.json.UTF8StreamJsonParser.nextFieldName(UTF8StreamJsonParser.java:989)\n\tat com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.BaseNodeDeserializer.deserializeObject(JsonNodeDeserializer.java:249)\n\tat com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.JsonNodeDeserializer.deserialize(JsonNodeDeserializer.java:68)\n\tat com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.JsonNodeDeserializer.deserialize(JsonNodeDeserializer.java:15)\n\tat com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._readTreeAndClose(ObjectMapper.java:4270)\n\tat com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.readTree(ObjectMapper.java:2734)\n\tat org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonDeserializer.deserialize(JsonDeserializer.java:64)\n\tat org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter.toConnectData(JsonConverter.java:322)\n\tat org.apache.kafka.connect.storage.Converter.toConnectData(Converter.java:87)\n\tat org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.convertValue(WorkerSinkTask.java:540)\n\tat org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.lambda$convertAndTransformRecord$2(WorkerSinkTask.java:496)\n\tat org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.errors.RetryWithToleranceOperator.execAndRetry(RetryWithToleranceOperator.java:156)\n\tat org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.errors.RetryWithToleranceOperator.execAndHandleError(RetryWithToleranceOperator.java:190)\n\tat org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.errors.RetryWithToleranceOperator.execute(RetryWithToleranceOperator.java:132)\n\tat org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.convertAndTransformRecord(WorkerSinkTask.java:496)\n\tat org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.convertMessages(WorkerSinkTask.java:473)\n\tat org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.poll(WorkerSinkTask.java:328)\n\tat org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.iteration(WorkerSinkTask.java:232)\n\tat org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.execute(WorkerSinkTask.java:201)\n\tat org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask.doRun(WorkerTask.java:182)\n\tat org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask.run(WorkerTask.java:231)\n\tat java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)\n\tat java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)\n\tat java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)\n\tat java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)\n\tat java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)\n"
      }
   ],
   "type":"sink"
}
```

I am writing  sample json record to kafka topic.

```
./kafka-console-producer.sh  --topic sinktest2 --bootstrap-server   sample-kafka-kafka-bootstrap:9093 --producer.config  /persistent/client.txt < /persistent/emp.json
```

emp.json is below file

```
{
    "employee": {
        "name":       "abc",
        "salary":      56000,
        "married":    true
    }
}
```

I don't see any logs in connector pod and no databse and collection being created in mongodb.

Please help to resolve this issue. Thank you !!

Comment: Can you share you kafka-connect configuration ? And i think you are missing key and value converter, and schema

Answer (score 1):

I think you are missing some configuration parameters like converter, and schema.

Update your config to add following:

```
"key.converter":"org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter",
"value.converter":"org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter",
"key.converter.schemas.enable": "false",
"value.converter.schemas.enable": "false",
```

If you are using KafkaConnect on kubernetes, you may create the sink connector as shown below. Create a file with name like `mongo-sink-connector.yaml`

```
apiVersion: kafka.strimzi.io/v1beta2
kind: KafkaConnector
metadata:
  name: mongodb-sink-connector
  labels:
    strimzi.io/cluster: my-connect-cluster
spec:
  class: com.mongodb.kafka.connect.MongoSinkConnector
  tasksMax: 2
  config:
    connection.uri: "mongodb://root:password@mongodb-0.mongodb-headless.default.svc.cluster.local:27017"
    database: test
    collection: sink
    topics: sink-topic
    key.converter: org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter
    value.converter: org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter
    key.converter.schemas.enable: false
    value.converter.schemas.enable: false
```

Execute the command:

```
$ kubectl apply -f mongo-sink-connector.yaml
```

you should see the output:

```
kafkaconnector.kafka.strimzi.io/mongo-apps-sink-connector created
```

Before starting the producer, check the status of connector and verify the topic has created as follows:

Status:

```
[kafka@my-connect-cluster-connect-5d47fb574-69xpv kafka]$ curl http://localhost:8083/connectors/mongodb-sink-connector/status
{"name":"mongodb-sink-connector","connector":{"state":"RUNNING","worker_id":"IP-ADDRESS:8083"},"tasks":[{"id":0,"state":"RUNNING","worker_id":"IP-ADDRESS:8083"},{"id":1,"state":"RUNNING","worker_id":"IP-ADDRESS:8083"}],"type":"sink"}
[kafka@my-connect-cluster-connect-5d47fb574-69xpv kafka]$
```

Check topic creation, you will see `sink-topic`

```
[kafka@my-connect-cluster-connect-5d47fb574-69xpv kafka]$  bin/kafka-topics.sh --bootstrap-server my-cluster-kafka-bootstrap:9092 --list
__consumer_offsets
__strimzi-topic-operator-kstreams-topic-store-changelog
__strimzi_store_topic
connect-cluster-configs
connect-cluster-offsets
connect-cluster-status
sink-topic
```

Now, go on kafka server to execute the producer

```sh
[kafka@my-cluster-kafka-0 kafka]$  bin/kafka-console-producer.sh --broker-list my-cluster-kafka-bootstrap:9092 --topic sink-topic
```

Successful execution will show you a prompt like `>` to enter/test the data

```
>{"employee": {"name": "abc", "salary": 56000, "married": true}}
>
```

On anther terminal, connect to kafka server and start consumer to verify the data

```
[kafka@my-cluster-kafka-0 kafka]$ bin/kafka-console-consumer.sh --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 --topic sink-topic --from-beginning
{"employee": {"name": "abc", "salary": 56000, "married": true}}
```

If you see this data, means everything is working fine. Now let us check on mongodb. Connect with your mongodb server and check

```
rs0:PRIMARY> use test
switched to db test
rs0:PRIMARY> show collections
sink
rs0:PRIMARY> db.sink.find()
{ "_id" : ObjectId("6234a4a0dad1a2638f57a6b2"), "employee" : { "name" : "abc", "salary" : NumberLong(56000), "married" : true } }
```

et Voila!

Comment: Hi Faaiz, Thanks for your solution, I was missing config values.

Comment: Happy to know that it works for you !

Comment: If my MongoDB is enabled with TLS, then how can I mention certificates in connector ?

Comment: Does this also work for mongodb atlas ?

Comment: @chirag Ideally, there should not be any difference. Give a try and let us know if you face issues/errors.

Comment: @Faaiz thanks, do you have any advice on this topic ? [similar topic but in kubernetes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73815342/atlas-mongodb-sink-connector-for-strimzi-kafka-setup)

Comment: @chirag i put some comments on your above question. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

You're hitting a serialization exception. I'll break the message out a bit:

```
com.fasterxml.jackson.core.io.JsonEOFException: Unexpected end-of-input:
expected close marker for Object (start marker at [Source: (byte[])"{ "; line: 1, column: 1])

at [Source: (byte[])"{ "; line: 1, column: 4]

Caused by: com.fasterxml.jackson.core.io.JsonEOFException:

Unexpected end-of-input: expected close marker for Object (start marker at [Source: (byte[])"{ "; line: 1, column: 1])

at [Source: (byte[])"{ "; line: 1, column: 4]
```

"expected close marker for Object" suggests to me that the parser is expecting to see the entire JSON object as one line, rather than pretty-printed.

```json
{"employee": {"name": "abc", "salary": 56000, "married": true}}
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your response serialization issue got fix. Now I see other  error org.apache.kafka.connect.errors.DataException: JsonConverter with schemas.enable requires \"schema\" and \"payload\" fields and may not contain additional fields. If you are trying to deserialize plain JSON data, set schemas.enable=false in your converter configuration.\n\tat org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter.toConnectData(JsonConverter.java:328)\

Comment: @Khumar, check my reply :)