# Atlas MongoDB sink connector for strimzi kafka setup

Tags: mongodb, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, mongodb-atlas, strimzi

I am new kafka space and I have setup Strimzi cluster operator, Kafka bootstrap server, entity operator, and kafka connect in Kubernetes following the below guidelines:

https://strimzi.io/docs/operators/latest/deploying.html

How do I setup kafka mongo sink connector for strimzi kafka connect cluster ?

I have the official mongodb connector plugin. Can I use this plugin to connect to atlas mongodb ?

Most of the forums have explanation on confluent kafka but not strimzi kafka.

Below is my kafka connect config:

```
apiVersion: kafka.strimzi.io/v1beta2

kind: KafkaConnect

metadata:

  name: my-mongo-connect

  annotations:

    strimzi.io/use-connector-resources: "true"

spec:

  image: STRIMZI KAFKA CONNECT IMAGE WITH MONGODB PLUGIN

  version: 3.2.1

  replicas: 1

  bootstrapServers:  my-cluster-kafka-bootstrap:9092

  logging:

    type: inline

    loggers:

      connect.root.logger.level: "INFO"

  config:

    group.id:  my-cluster

    offset.storage.topic: mongo-connect-cluster-offsets

    config.storage.topic: mongo-connect-cluster-configs

    status.storage.topic: mongo-connect-cluster-status

    key.converter: org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter

    value.converter: org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter

    key.converter.schemas.enable: true

    value.converter.schemas.enable: true

    config.storage.replication.factor: -1

    offset.storage.replication.factor: -1

    status.storage.replication.factor: -1
```

Below is my sink connector config:

```
apiVersion: kafka.strimzi.io/v1beta2

kind: KafkaConnector

metadata:

  name: mongodb-sink-connector

  labels:

    strimzi.io/cluster: my-cluster

spec:

  class: com.mongodb.kafka.connect.MongoSinkConnector

  tasksMax: 2

  config:

    topics: my-topic

    connection.uri: "MONGO ATLAS CONNECTION STRING"

    database: my_database

    collection: my_collection

    post.processor.chain: com.mongodb.kafka.connect.sink.processor.DocumentIdAdder,com.mongodb.kafka.connect.sink.processor.KafkaMetaAdder

    key.converter: org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter

    key.converter.schemas.enable: false

    value.converter: org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter

    value.converter.schemas.enable: false
```

But the above setup is not working though my kafka server is up and running producer-consumer example works.

Is the official mongodb plugin (Maven Central Repository Search) appropriate for this ? or do I use debezium mongodb connector ?

If anyone can shed some light on step-by-step guideline with this regard, that would of great help.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Debezium only reads from databases, not writes

Comment: What specific error are you getting? There's no such thing as "Confluent Kafka". Bootstrap servers work the same way because it's only **Apache** Kafka. Similarly, Mongo works the same way too, including in Atlas

Comment: @OneCricketeer No error shows up in pod logs. When I start the producer pod to run a sample data ingestion, nothing happens. How do I check what is happening exactly between kafka connect cluster and kafka bootstrap server? Also which sink connector plugin do I use for this purpose ?

Comment: @OneCricketeer `kubectl -n kafka run kafka-producer -ti --image=quay.io/strimzi/kafka:0.23.0-kafka-2.8.0 --rm=true --restart=Never -- bin/kafka-console-producer.sh --broker-list my-cluster-kafka-bootstrap:9092 --topic my-topic` and `kubectl -n kafka run kafka-consumer -ti --image=quay.io/strimzi/kafka:0.23.0-kafka-2.8.0 --rm=true --restart=Never -- bin/kafka-console-consumer.sh --bootstrap-server my-cluster-kafka-bootstrap:9092 --topic my-topic --from-beginning` works fine, produced message is recieved. So the kafka server has no problem. I'm missing something which I have not idea about.

Comment: What do you mean "nothing happens"? Connect framework doesn't print any data when it consumes unless the connector itself has explicit logs to do so (Mongo Connector is open source, you can go look at what logs to expect). You'd use Mongo Sink Connector; there's only one that I know about. Your connector resource needs a `namespace: kafka` definition, by the way

Comment: If you simply want to debug Kafka Connect in Strimzi, start with FileSink

Comment: @OneCriketeer Yes exactly. It does not show any logs showing the message has received. Regarding the namespace, while deploying the yaml I apply with `-n kafka`. This should be enough ?

Comment: [Mongo kafka connect from official mongodb](https://search.maven.org/artifact/org.mongodb.kafka/mongo-kafka-connect/1.8.0/jar) is it this ?

Comment: You need to enable debug logs https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-kafka/blob/master/src/main/java/com/mongodb/kafka/connect/sink/StartedMongoSinkTask.java#L145

Comment: Yes, that's the JAR. If your image doesn't have that JAR on its plugin path, you should expect to see an error in the Connect pod for sure

Comment: Got it. I will try it out and let you know. Thanks, @OneCricketeer

Comment: @chirag Can you share the `Dockerfile` contents that you used to build the image `STRIMZI KAFKA CONNECT IMAGE WITH MONGODB PLUGIN` ?

Comment: Also, you don't need `post.processor.chain` in `mongodb-sink-connector`.  Regarding `KafkaConnect`, you are missing `tls` in `spec:` and i see, may be some issue in `config:` probabily in `group-id`. In `KafkaConnect`, you don't need `key.converter` and `key.converter.schema.enable` because it's in `KafkaConnector`. Will try to write complete the answer soon.

Comment: I see from you comment your consumer and producer the version of image you are using. Is this the image you used to build the kafka connect image `--image=quay.io/strimzi/kafka:0.23.0-kafka-2.8.0` ? If yes, then clearly there is mismatch of version in your `KafkaConnect` spec.

Comment: It would be nice if you share the output from your kafka connect pod by executing following IN YOUR QUESTION:


`kubectl -n kafka exec -it YOUR-KAFKA-CONNECT-POD -- curl http://localhost:8083/connectors`

`kubectl -n kafka exec -it YOUR-KAFKA-CONNECT-POD -- bin/kafka-topics.sh --bootstrap-server my-cluster-kafka-bootstrap:9092 --list`

Answer (score 0):

Since the comment section is getting longer, I'm posting some of the answers to the questions asked in the comments.

Below is my dockerfile:

```
FROM quay.io/strimzi/kafka:0.31.0-kafka-3.2.1
USER root:root
COPY ./my-plugins/ /opt/kafka/plugins/
USER 1001
```

`my-plugins` folder contains two jar files `mongo-kafka-connect-1.8.0.jar` and `mongodb-driver-core-4.7.1.jar`. I'm not sure if I need the core-driver plugin for atlas mongodb, but anyway I have it there.

I changed the producer-consumer example version to the following:

```
kubectl -n kafka run kafka-producer -ti --image=quay.io/strimzi/kafka:0.31.0-kafka-3.2.1 --rm=true --restart=Never -- bin/kafka-console-producer.sh --broker-list my-cluster-kafka-bootstrap:9092 --topic my-topic
```

To summerize, my `strimzi operator is 0.31.0` and `kafka-connect is set to 3.2.1` which is aligned with the [compatibility table here under supported versions](https://strimzi.io/downloads/)

Regarding adding `tls` `spec` section in kafka-connect, the liveness-probe fails saying: `failed to connect to the IP-ADDRESS` and the pod keeps restarting.

Below is my tls spec where the cert  is present in my kafka server:

```
tls:
     trustedCertificates:
      - secretName: my-cluster-cluster-ca-cert 
        certificate: ca.crt
```

I removed the key converter configs as suggested. But what should the `group.id` in my kafka-connect ?

I also changed `storage.topic` config to the following:

```
   offset.storage.topic: mongo-connect-cluster-offsets
   config.storage.topic: mongo-connect-cluster-configs
   status.storage.topic: mongo-connect-cluster-status
```

I referred [this blog](https://dzone.com/articles/data-pipeline-using-mongodb-and-kafka-connect-on-k) for the above settings.

The log from `kubectl -n kafka exec -it YOUR-KAFKA-CONNECT-POD -- curl http://localhost:8083/connectors` is `[]` so there is a problem here?

The log from `kubectl -n kafka exec -it YOUR-KAFKA-CONNECT-POD -- bin/kafka-topics.sh --bootstrap-server my-cluster-kafka-bootstrap:9092 --list`:

```
__consumer_offsets
__strimzi-topic-operator-kstreams-topic-store-changelog
__strimzi_store_topic
mongo-connect-cluster-configs
mongo-connect-cluster-offsets
mongo-connect-cluster-status
my-topic
```

Below is pod logs for kafka-connect, I will find a way to share the whole log files soon.

[image: kafka-connect]

So, where am I going wrong? Also, how do I verify that the data flow is happening the way it is intended to?

Comment: @Faaiz I hope, I answered your questions.